# Regex dot issues

Tags: java, regex

I have a class `NumericTextField extends JTextField`.It only allows inputs based on a regex.What i need it to do is to only allow doubles.Most inputs if not all will be like `1` or `1.25` or `30.35` and so on.So it needs to only allow digits and only one decimal point.Till now i used a regex that allows more then one dot.
I tried a couple of regex like the following :

`^\\d*(\\.\\d+)?$`

`\\d*(\\.)?\\d+`

`(?<=^| )\\d+(\\.\\d+)?(?=$| )|(?<=^| )\\.\\d+(?=$| )`

`[0-9]+(?:\\.[0-9]*)?`

And many more.The problem is that it won't accept the dot(unless i copy-paste),it will only accept digits.I'm trying to input it via the `>` key,my keyboard doesn't have a numeric keypad.Could that be the issue ? if so,how can i make it so that it only accepts one dot,the one near the letters,the `>` one?

How can i fix this ?

Here is the class :

```
 @SuppressWarnings("serial")
 class NumericTextField extends JTextField {

@Override
protected Document createDefaultModel() {
    return new NumericDocument();
}

private static class NumericDocument extends PlainDocument {
    // The regular expression to match input against (zero or more digits)

    private final static Pattern DIGITS = Pattern.compile("-?\\d+(\\.\\d+)?");

    @Override
    public void insertString(int offs, String str, AttributeSet a) throws BadLocationException {
        // Only insert the text if it matches the regular expression
        if (str != null && DIGITS.matcher(str).matches()) {
            super.insertString(offs, str, a);
        }
    }
}
}
```

Comment: How about not using regex and do a test like the answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1102891/how-to-check-if-a-string-is-a-numeric-type-in-java

Answer (score 1):

`^-?\d+(\.\d+)?$` will allow for 1 or 1.X+ if that's what you're going for.

Comment: This will not work for negative numbers (and don't know if the OP needs to deal with negative numbers)

Comment: Same thing.It allows for example 2.2 if i copy paste it but not if i try and input it myself by keyboard

Comment: very strange. never seen a `.` entered by keyboard not count as a `.` character.

Answer (score 0):

Try this one:

```
str.matches("^-?\\d+(\\.\\d+)?$");
```

It worked in the example *(reusing your code)*:

```
import java.util.regex.Pattern;
import java.util.regex.Matcher;

public class HelloWorld{
    private final static Pattern DIGITS = Pattern.compile("-?\\d+(\\.\\d+)?");

     public static void main(String []args){
        String str = "2.2";

        // Only insert the text if it matches the regular expression
        if (str != null && DIGITS.matcher(str).matches()) {
            System.out.println("passed");
        }else{
            System.out.println("refused");
        }
     }
}
```

Comment: As with the post by tenub,it allows for example 2.2 if i copy paste it but not if i try and input it myself by keyboard.I posted the class i use,maybe there's something wrong with it

Comment: insert a comment with the `2.2` typed

Comment: This is me typing 2.2

Comment: O_o" looks normal... see it pasted here [regex 101 example](http://regex101.com/r/rU3sX2)

Comment: Yea,weird.Could you please take my class and try and create a `new NumericTextField` ? I have added the full class.Maybe it's my laptop or something...

Answer (score 0):

Try,

`(-|\\+)?[0-9]+(\\.[0-9]+)?`

[image]

```
String pattern = "(-|\\+)?[0-9]+(\\.[0-9]+)?";
String string = "2.2";
System.out.println(string.matches(pattern));
```

it prints `true`

Comment: Prints true as well.Added that to a new project to be all clean and stuff,still won't let me input `.` by keyboard.Weird